# Beautifulsoup Webscraping: How to get information with javascript?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to webscrape a specific page from Choice Hotel's website (specifically https://www.choicehotels.com/tennessee/nashville/hotels ) to create a list of all choice hotels in Nashville, TN. When I open the page and open up my developer's tools, I can see the information I'm looking for under `<div class="list">`, however, when I attempt to scrape the site, I cannot find this tag. I can't seem to find anything deeper than `<div class="animate-fade z-index-90">`, which any tags on a deeper level than that just return "None". However, I do see a lot of Javascript towards the bottom. I believe this is due to the request not seeing what I see when I open the page in my browser. How might I make my program able to see the tags that I see?

This is how I am attempting the scrape:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

source = request.get("https://www.choicehotels.com/tennessee/nashville/hotels").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
list = soup.find('div', class_='list')
print(list)
```

Is there something I'm not doing, or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the page JavaScript accesses directly using a POST request. It returns a JSON object with you can parse the way you would parse any JSON.

```
import requests

data = {'adults':   '1',
'checkInDate':  '2018-09-08',
'checkOutDate': '2018-09-09',
'hotelSortOrder':   'RELEVANCE',
'include':  'amenity_groups, amenity_totals, rating, relative_media',
'lat':  '36.167839',
'lon':  '-86.77816',
'minors':   '0',
'optimizeResponse': 'image_url',
'placeId':  '414666',
'placeName':    'Nashville, TN, US',
'placeType':    'City',
'platformType': 'DESKTOP',
'preferredLocaleCode':  'en-us',
'ratePlanCode': 'RACK',
'ratePlans':    'RACK,PREPD,PROMO,FENCD',
'rateType': 'LOW_ALL',
'searchRadius': '25',
'siteOpRelevanceSortMethod':    'ALGORITHM_B',}

r = requests.post('https://www.choicehotels.com/webapi/location/hotels', data = data)

for h in r.json()['hotels']:
    print(h['name'])
    print (h['description'])
```

Outputs:

```
Comfort Inn Downtown Nashville-Vanderbilt
Get rested and ready for anything when you stay at the Comfort Inn Downtown Nashville-Vanderbilt hotel in Nashville, TN. We are merely minutes from the Nashville International Airport and conveniently located near Vanderbilt University and the Nashville Convention Center. Each comfortable room is furnished with a flat-screen TV, hair dryer, coffee maker, microwave and more. We also offer free WiFi, a fitness center and outdoor pool. Get going with a free hot breakfast including eggs, waffles and meat plus healthy options like yogurt and fresh fruit. Also, earn rewards including free nights and gift cards with our Choice Privileges Rewards program. 
Comfort Suites Airport
Get more of the space you need to spread out, relax or work at the smoke-free Comfort Suites Airport hotel in Nashville, TN, located near the Grand Ole Opry. Nearby attractions include Opry Mills, Ryman Auditorium, Music City Bowl and Music City Center. Nashville Convention Center, Sommet Center, BridgestoneFirestone and Antique Archaeology are also close. Enjoy free hot breakfast, free WiFi, free airport transportation, fitness center and a seasonal outdoor pool. Your spacious room includes a flat-screen TV, hair dryer, sofa sleeper, microwave and refrigerator. Also, earn rewards including free nights and gift cards with our Choice Privileges Rewards program. 
Clarion Hotel Nashville Downtown - Stadium
Get more value at the 100 percent smoke-free Clarion Hotel Nashville Downtown-Stadium in Nashville, TN. We are near Nissan Stadium, Country Music Hall of Fame, Ryman Auditorium, Vanderbilt University and Bridgestone Arena. Life is better when you get together--enjoy such amenities as free WiFi, ample free parking, free breakfast, free downtown shuttle, business and fitness centers and restaurant. Your guest room features a refrigerator, microwave, coffee maker, hair dryer, iron and ironing board. Also, earn rewards including free nights and gift cards with our Choice Privileges Rewards program.  CC required at check-in. Shuttle runs from 8 am-9 pm on the hour. 
The Capitol Hotel Downtown, an Ascend Hotel Collection Member
Let the destination reach you at The Capitol Hotel Downtown, an Ascend Hotel Collection Member in Nashville, TN. Our smoke-free, upscale property is conveniently located near many key performing arts and sports facilities for which this iconic city is known. All guestrooms include coffee makers, hair dryers, irons and ironing boards, desks, safes, refrigerators and more. Enjoy free breakfast, free WiFi, a fitness center and business center. Then, relax in our bar and bistro at the end of your day. Also, earn rewards including free nights and gift cards with our Choice Privileges Rewards program. 
Sleep Inn
The Sleep Inn hotel in Nashville, TN will give you a simply stylish experience. Were close to attractions like the the Grand Ole Opry, Nashville Convention Center, Opry Mills and the Sommet Center. Enjoy free breakfast, free WiFi, free weekday newspaper, a seasonal outdoor pool and guest laundry facilities. Your guest room offers warm, modern designs, and includes a flat-screen TV in addition to standard room amenities. Some rooms have microwaves, refrigerators, coffee makers, irons and ironing boards. Also, earn rewards including free nights and gift cards with our Choice Privileges Rewards program.
```

Comment: If I was to use this method, would I still be able to view the html? Because I am needing to get the exact address for the hotels.

Comment: There is also a tag that is of interest to me located a little deeper than the list - That being a <div> tag with an "id" that contains a 5 digit code - For example, <div (several parameters, most of which include selenium things) id='hotel-TN731'>. Would this be able to be viewed?

Comment: print(h['address']) which you can further parse with JSON and print(h['id'])

Comment: Much appreciated Dan! I'm very grateful for your help! You've solved it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to process the JavaScript, you can use selenium to process JS. See the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.choicehotels.com/tennessee/nashville/hotels")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="address"]')))
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
list = soup.find('div', class_='list')
print(list)
driver.close()
```

Comment: I have installed selenium via pip. I attempted to run this exact code, but I'm receiving the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'By' from 'selenium.webdriver.common' (C:\users\myUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\__init__.py)". I have verified that the path to this file is located in my 'path' environment variable. What does this mean?